# How do I dispatch an action inside setTimeout in createAsyncThunk?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am learning how to use createAsyncThunk.
I have created a simple counter app. It has an add and an subtract button. On clicking those buttons, the counter value with increase or decrease accordingly.

Now I want to add two more buttons which on clicking should do the same increment and decrement but it should be delayed by one second.

I am able to achieve the same when I don't use redux toolkit. This
[StackBlitz has the code without toolkit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vihbhq?file=src%2FApp.js)

But I am not sure how to approach the same using redux toolkit.
Can someone guide me how I should write my createAsyncThunk call and extraReducers to achieve the same?

This [Stackblitz contains an example of what I had tried with toolkit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9d4fxl?file=src%2FCounter.js,src%2Fstore.js,src%2FcounterSlice2.js)

I am not sure how to proceed with my `createAsyncThunk` call. I tried to dispatch the action inside the `createAsync` callback, but it did not work.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const asyncAdd = createAsyncThunk('asyncAdd', async (_, thunkAPI) => {


});
const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    count: 0,
    hasError: false,
    isLoading: false,
    users: {},
    todos: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => {
      state.count += action.payload;
    },
    sub: (state) => {
      state.count -= 1;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [asyncAdd.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.hasError = false;
      state.isLoading = true;
      console.log('PENDING');
    },
    [asyncAdd.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.hasError = false;
      state.isLoading = false;
      console.log('payload ' + action.payload);
      state.count = action.payload;
      console.log('FULILLED');
    },
    [asyncAdd.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.hasError = true;
      state.isLoading = false;
      console.log('REJECTED');
    },
  },
});

export const { add, sub } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createAsyncThunk` is designed to process some late action using `promises`, you have to return either a `promise` or a resolved promise value.

> Use `builder` object in `extraReducers` to create pending, rejected and fullfilled cases

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

//method one using inbuild await
export const asyncAdd = createAsyncThunk('aextraReducerssyncAdd', (count) => {

  return new Promise((res) => { // return a promise that resolves after one second
    setTimeout(res, 1000, count); 
  });
});

//method two using await
export const asyncAdd2 = createAsyncThunk('asyncAdd',async (count) => {

  const res = await new Promise((res) => { // return a promise that resolves after one second
    setTimeout(res, 1000, count); 
  });
  return res;
});

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    count: 0,
    hasError: false,
    isLoading: false,
    users: {},
    todos: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => {
      state.count += action.payload;
    },
    sub: (state) => {
      state.count -= 1;
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) { //use builer
    builder.addCase(asyncAdd.fulfilled, function (state, { payload }) {
      state.count += payload;
    }).addCase(asyncAdd.pending,function (state) {
      state.isLoading = true;
    }).addCase(asyncAdd.rejected,function (state) {
      state.hasError = true;
    });
  },
});

export const { add, sub } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

I have forked the stackblitz also

Comment: Thank you, but when I try, it does not wait for 1000ms. Can you please share the link that you forked? I'd like to see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Because you have just created `counterSlice2` file but forget to change the import from `./counterSlice` to '`./counterSlice2` in `Counter.js` line no:4